# row count of all the tables in SQL manager for interbase and firebird

Tags: sql, sql-server, firebird, interbase

I'm using sql manager for **interbase and firebird** , i have around *130 tables* i  want to count rows of all the tables in sql script. why i'm choosing the sql manager for interbase and firebird is my back up file in GDB formate , i already restore the GDB file, i need to count the rows.
i tried this query but its not working

```
USE DatabaseName
GO
CREATE TABLE #temp (
table_name sysname ,
row_count INT,
reserved_size VARCHAR(50), 
data_size VARCHAR(50),
index_size VARCHAR(50),
unused_size VARCHAR(50))
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT #temp
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'sp_spaceused ''?'''
SELECT a.table_name,
a.row_count,
COUNT(*) AS col_count,
a.data_size
FROM #temp a
INNER JOIN information_schema.columns b
ON a.table_name collate database_default
= b.table_name collate database_default
GROUP BY a.table_name, a.row_count, a.data_size
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(a.data_size, ' KB', '') AS integer) DESC
DROP TABLE #temp
```

it give error -104.

Comment: was `INSERT #temp` meant to be `INSERT INTO #temp`?

Comment: @mirkobrankovic - yes. `INTO` is not necessarily in the construct.

Comment: Your code is TSQL specifically for Microsoft SQL Server. So it doesn't work with Firebird or Interbase.

Answer (score 3):

To get a record count of all tables in a database, you can use this script from Firebird FAQ item ["How to get record count for all tables?"](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq376/). I copied the script below for completeness:

```
set term !! ;
EXECUTE BLOCK
returns ( stm varchar(60), cnt integer )
as
BEGIN
   for select cast('select count(*) from "'||trim(r.RDB$RELATION_NAME)||'"' as varchar(60)) 
       from RDB$RELATIONS r
       where (r.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG is null or r.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0) 
       and r.RDB$VIEW_BLR is null
       order by 1
   into :stm
   DO
   BEGIN
      execute statement :stm into :cnt;
      suspend;
   END
END
```

Note that this counts only records visible to your current transaction. This script will work in Firebird (I tested it with Firebird 2.5), but probably not for Interbase as the Firebird and Interbase dialect have diverged a bit in the last 13 years.

Comment: i'm using firebird lower version, its not support both EXECUTE and trim functions

Comment: The FAQ item I linked to also supplies a version that should work with old versions of Firebird. And otherwise: consider upgrading. Firebird 2.5 has been out for 3 years, and afaik this should even work with Firebird 2.0, which has been out for 7 years.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean with "sql manager" (probably some MS SQL Server tool?) but the SQL you posted isn't Firebird compatible, yes.

The Firebird has special `gstat` (command line) tool to analyse database. The [manual is available online](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gstat.html). However, AFAIK the closest thing to record count it reports is the node count in PK index.

It would be possible to create stored procedure which reads the table names from system tables and queries each for count but is it worth doing it really depends why do you need the record count.

Comment: yes its not firebird compatible, i'm new to firebird that's why.

Comment: i install this tool to windows,when i Connect the database into firebird using command line is not working that's why i use sql manager for interbase, because the DB file is around 1.2 GB

Comment: Your question is a real mess... you mention GDB file which suggest you use Interbase but here you wrote that you use Firebird and it looks like you're tring to use some MS SQL Server specific tool to work with this DB... you shoud update your question with the info about the DB engine you use (with version number) and include full error message you get when tring some command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (with fix) -

```
SELECT 
      o.[object_id]
    , [object_name] = s.name + '.' + o.name
     , c.col_count
     , r.row_count
     , data_size  = CAST(r.pages * 8 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' KB'
FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
JOIN (
     SELECT c.[object_id], col_count = COUNT(1)
     FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
     GROUP BY c.[object_id]
) c ON c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
JOIN (
     SELECT
          p.[object_id]
          , row_count = SUM(p.[rows])
        , pages = SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN a.[type] != 1 AND p.index_id < 2 THEN a.used_pages
                WHEN p.index_id < 2 THEN a.data_pages ELSE 0
            END
            )
    FROM sys.partitions p
    JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.[partition_id] = a.container_id
     WHERE p.index_id IN (0, 1)
     GROUP BY p.[object_id]
) r ON r.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE o.[type] = 'U' 
ORDER BY r.pages DESC
```

Comment: Unless the "sql manager" tool does some magic this won't work with Firebird / Interbase - there is no `sys.objects`, `sys.schemas` etc objects in these RDBMS.

Comment: @ain, you are right. Initially I misunderstood the question. :( This script just a analogue of the above query.